# Why does this program not give the expected output?

Tags: c, for-loop, int

This program (in C) doesn't output what I'd expect:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j ;
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= 2 ; i++ )
    {
        for ( j = 1 ; j <= 2 ; j++ )
        {
            if ( i == j )
                continue ;
            printf ( "\n%d %d\n", i, j ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

I think it should be

```
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 3
```

But the program outputs

```
1 2
2 1
```

Why is this?

Comment: the question is: why do you think it should start with 1 3 and not 1 2?

Comment: after executing printf second time  i.e after printing 1 2 , the   control redirects to inner for loop , which on verification of the condition " j<=2" turns true as j is now 2 , so it gets incremented by 1 and turns 3 and then enters the loop again . this is what i feel , any mistakes correct me!!

Comment: What output do you expect without the `if`?

Comment: the control even verifies the condition even after incrementing it , so 3 turns out to be false , hence the output.

Comment: @pmg without "if"  the output  would be  1 1  1 2   2 1    2 2

Comment: So ... where would the 1 3 and 2 3 come from. The absence of the `if` cannot create new numbers, can it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number 3 cannot be ever reached by the loops' indices.

Answer (score 1):

The values of `i` and `j` go through this sequence:

```
i j
---
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2
```

Note that the `i++` and `j++` increments happen **after** each iteration of the loop body.

The only cases where your `printf` is called are where `i` and `j` are different. That means you get:

```
1 2
2 1
```